# c++ operator overload in an enum class

Tags: c++, class, enums, overloading, operator-keyword

So I'm writing a game using c++ and in my tutorial state, I have different steps that the user goes through, explaining how the game works.  I want to increment which step the user is on after a certain action is performed. (Mouse click). I tried overloading the `++` operator but I get an error saying `binary '++': 'STEPS' does not define this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined operator`. I'm using visual studio and it's error code `C2676`.

I have my enum class set up as follows:

```
enum class STEPS
{
    ONE,
    TWO,
    END_OF_LIST
};

STEPS& operator++(STEPS& s)
{
    s = staic_cast<STEPS>(static_cast<int>(s) + 1);
    if (s == STEPS::END_OF_LIST)
    {
        s = static_cast<STEPS>(static_cast<int>(s) - 1);
    }
    return s;
}
```

In my updating function of my tutorial state class I check if the mouse was clicked. If it was I'm trying to increment steps.

// this is defined in the header and set to STEPS::ONE upon initialization
`STEPS steps;`

```
TutorialState::Update()
{
    // If mouse was clicked
    if (mouse.Left())
    {
        steps++; // this is giving me an error.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 15):

```
STEPS& operator++(STEPS& s);
```

is for `++step`.

for `step++`, you need

```
STEPS operator++(STEPS& s, int) { auto res = s; ++s; return res; }
```

It has been chosen to use extra parameter `int` to distinguish between pre and post increment operator.

You may read http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_incdec for more details.

Comment: Hmm. I'm new to the overloading operators but I'll definitely check it out. It's all still fuzzy to me. Thanks for the quick reply!